# Is there a hyperkaehler manifold whose mirror is the total space of a tangent/cotangent bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, k3-surfaces, mirror-symmetry

I am looking for an example of a hyperkaehler manifold $Y$ whose mirror is the total space of a tangent bundle $TX$ or a cotangent bundle $T^*X$, where $X$ can be any Riemannian manifold.

Is such a pair known to exist?

I should add that I am not interested in mirrors which are Landau-Ginzburg (LG) pairs which include (the total spaces of) $TX$ or $T^*X$ together with an LG superpotential, but instead just a mirror manifold with no other data.

Comment: It's easy to find such an example. Say let $Y$ be $(\mathbb{C}^\ast)^{2n}$, then it's self mirror, so $X$ is symplectomorphic to $T^\ast(T^{2n})$. But I think if you don't want an LG potential, all you can get are just trivial examples.

Comment: Thank you. May I know why it is the case that if I do not want any LG potential, then all I can get are trivial examples?